# Multiple onbeforeunload() and onunload() events

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onbeforeunload

I have a strange issue from a client in that our code, which they include uses `onbeforeunload()` to trigger a dialog, but they are also including another companies code which also binds this event handler.

Is it possible for both to execute at the same time?

I've been reading this, http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596101992 "JavaScript: The Definitive Guide, Fifth Edition" to try and help better understand what is happening in the browsers internals and the Javascript stack, but it's proving quite mind bending.

I understand from reading the book that some events can be executed all at the same time if they are attached using the Level 2 API `addEventListener()` but the order will be up to the browser. However there is no mention of the `onbeforeunload()` event. Just the `onunload()`.

Which leads me to the second part of the question. If an event is triggered in `onbeforeunload()` am I right in thinking that unless it returns true, the `onunload()` will never be called?

If anyone can shed some light on it, or hook me up with a nice tutorial/guide on either having multiple event handlers assigned to the same event, or specifically on these two events that would be ace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it possible for both to execute at the same time?

Not *literally* at the same time, no — Javascript in browsers is (currently) single-threaded. So there can be multiple handlers for the `onbeforeunload` event, but they'll be called serially, not simultaneously. At least in theory; in practice, it looks like only one of them is called (see below).

> If an event is triggered in onbeforeunload() am I right in thinking that unless it returns true, the onunload() will never be called?

If any `onbeforeunload` handler cancels the unload, no `onunload` handler will be called. You cancel the unload by doing two things (because browsers differ here): First, you assign a string to the `returnValue` property of the `event` object, and then you return that string out of the function. Details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907(VS.85).aspx) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload). (The string is used as a prompt, allowing the user to decide whether to cancel the unload.)

#### Quick Test

So much for theory, let's look at what actually happens:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test Page</title>
<style type='text/css'>
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload = pageInit;
function pageInit() {
    hook(window, 'beforeunload', beforeUnload1);
    hook(window, 'beforeunload', beforeUnload2);
    hook(window, 'unload', unload1);
    hook(window, 'unload', unload2);
}

function beforeUnload1(event) {
    var s;

    event = event || window.event;
    s = "Message from beforeUnload1";
    event.returnValue = s
    return s;
}

function beforeUnload2(event) {
    var s;

    event = event || window.event;
    s = "Message from beforeUnload2";
    event.returnValue = s
    return s;
}

function unload1(event) {
    alert("Message from unload1");
}

function unload2(event) {
    alert("Message from unload2");
}

var hook = (function() {
    var d;

    function hookViaAttachEvent(obj, eventName, handler) {
        obj.attachEvent('on' + eventName, handler);
    }
    function hookViaAddEventListener(obj, eventName, handler) {
        obj.addEventListener(eventName, handler, false);
    }

    d = document.createElement('span');
    if (d.addEventListener) {
        return hookViaAddEventListener;
    }
    else if (d.attachEvent) {
        return hookViaAttachEvent;
    }
    throw "Neither attachEvent nor addEventListener found.";
})();
function hook(eventName, handler) {

}
</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

On Chrome, IE, and Firefox, I only ever see a notification from one of the `onbeforeunload` handlers, even when I say it's okay to go ahead and leave. I expect this is probably because otherwise, a sufficiently-irritating page could just register a bunch of handlers and keep nagging the user to stay on the page.

After the (one) question, if I allow navigation to continue, I get both unload messages.

Comment: Fab answer, thanks! Seems I'll have to work around it. Or extend our onbeforeunload() wrapper to pass through values depending on conditions.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with multiple unload listeners - only one gets fired...but only when I _don't_ have an alert call in one of the unload event handlers. Extremely weird. I'm thinking of posting a new question about it, unless there's perhaps a simple explanation that could go here?