# jQuery beforeunload cancel with submit for firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, onbeforeunload

I am having a heck of a time with this one guys.  I am trying to alert someone if they are trying to leave a page and have uploaded files already.  The tricky part is I want it to not warn them if they are submitting.  This is the strange part, the code I'm going to put in works in chrome but all the other browsers don't like it.  It is part of a plugin so just ignore some of the code.

```
  function cleanFiles(obj){
   var $obj = $(obj),
   $jForm = $obj.parents("form");
   $jForm.find("input[type=button]:last").not($obj).bind("click.save", function(event){
    $(window).unbind('beforeunload.cleanFile unload.removeFiles');
   });
   $(window).bind('beforeunload.cleanFile', function(event){
    var localSettings = $.extend({}, settings),
    filesList = "";
    $("input[type=hidden].fileFieldLists").each(function(){
     var $obj = $(this);
     filesList += ($obj.val() || "");
    });
    if(filesList.length){
     return localSettings.defaultLeaveMessage;
    }
    $(window).bind('unload.removeFiles', function(event){
     var filesList = [];
     $("input[type=hidden].fileFieldLists").each(function(){
      var $obj = $(this),
       localSettings = $.extend({}, settings, $obj.next().data()),
       fieldValues = ($obj.val().indexOf("*") ? $obj.val().split("*") : $obj.val()),
       fieldValuesCnt = fieldValues.length;
       for(var i = 0; i < fieldValuesCnt; i++){
        filesList.push(localSettings.filepath + fieldValues[i]);
       }
     });
     if(filesList.length){
      deleteFiles(filesList.join(","), false);
     }
    });
   });
  }
```

Comment: 1-space indentation is horrible to read.

Comment: What do you to `cleanFiles` method?

Comment: Thanks, but it compiles faster.  Anyone have anything useful to say?

Comment: its the object from the plugin, basically coming from buttons.

Comment: It may compile faster but it makes it harder for others to solve and therefore, less likely - @ThiefMaster wasn't complaining, simply telling you how to get better responses... To get to a useful point, I'm assuming nothing elsewhere is binding to `onbeforeunload`? [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2819834/156755) may be helpful as it highlights the differences between browsers in how they handle the event/cancelling it.

Comment: Yes the onbeforeunload binding is only called once.  I am going to try creating a calling function outside of the binding to see if that works.  Thanks Basic.

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/04/death-to-the-space-infidels.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found it.  Apparently in IE and Firefox the "click" event is fired after the "beforeUnload" event.  However the "mouseup" event fires before both of them so that was my solution.  I bound it to "click" and "mouseup" like so

```
$jForm.find("input[type=button]:last").not($obj).bind("click.save mouseup.save", function(event){
```

and it works in all browsers now... man what I would do for browsers to be consistent. Thanks for all the responses.